# silverlight streaming hosting

Tags: silverlight, hosting

Microsoft provides service at silverlight.live.com to provide hosting service, I am wondering whether there are some products which enables us to host silverlight streaming locally, e.g. hosting in IIS or in some file server?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight applications can be hosted on any web server: a Silverlight application is just a file with a .xap extension that the html page references.

Or are you looking at providing mms streaming for media content in your Silverlight app?

Comment: "are you looking at providing mms streaming for media content in your Silverlight app" -- yes. Any comments and ideas?

Comment: Even Silverlight Streaming doesn't provide MMS - its name is perhaps not the best. Any regular Windows Media Streaming Server can be used, though the trend these days is towards HTTP.